# How to make this query in laravel Query builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

```
SELECT
                        p.*, (IF(dp.Rate, dp.Rate, p.Rate)) AS Rate
                    FROM
                        visp.packages p LEFT JOIN (SELECT
                                        *
                                    From
                                        visp.dealer_packages
                                    Where
                                        DealerID = 56 OR DealerID = 0
                                   ) dp on dp.PackageID = p.packageID
                    WHERE p.Status = 1 AND (IsPublic = 1 AND dp.Status is NULL OR dp.Status = 1) AND IsDealerCanAdd = 1 ORDER BY
                    p.PackageOrdering
```

How to make this query in laravel-querybuilder ?

Comment: what you tried ?

Comment: $s="SELECT * From dealer_packages Where DealerID = 56 OR DealerID = 0";
              $query = DB::table('packages AS p')->select('p.*','(IF(dp.Rate, dp.Rate, p.Rate)) AS Rate')
            ->leftjoin( DB::raw("$s").'dealer_packages AS dp', 'dp.PackageID', '=', 'p.packageID')->get();

Comment: Had a look on this ? https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries

Comment: $s="SELECT * From dealer_packages Where DealerID = 56 OR DealerID = 0";
              $query = DB::table('packages AS p')->select('p.*','(IF(dp.Rate, dp.Rate, p.Rate)) AS Rate')
            ->leftjoin( DB::raw("$s").'dealer_packages AS dp', 'dp.PackageID', '=', 'p.packageID')
                ->whereRaw(" p.Status = 1 AND (IsPublic = 1 AND dp.Status is NULL OR dp.Status = 1) ORDER BY
     p.PackageOrdering");